# Add toolbar using Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, toolbar

I am writing a Greasemonkey script and I want to add a toolbar at the top of every website that I have the script enable on, but I'm not sure how this can be done (using JS). I want the toolbar to provide a dropdown list, as for each choice for the dropdown list, it does different stuff to the enabled website. Any other method that does this is appreciated.
Thank you!

Suppose I have this as my .js file:

```
var searchRE = new RegExp("red","gi"); 
var replace = 'blue'; 
for (var i=0;i<textNodes.snapshotLength;i++) { 
    var node = textNodes.snapshotItem(i); 
    node.data = node.data(searchRE, replace); 
}
```

Should I just put document.createElement... here? Thank you!

Comment: `document.createElement`, and go from there...

Comment: Can I just add this to my .js file..?

Comment: Greasemonkey is basically just javascript running on the page with elevated privileges, create your elements, style, then append to the body.

Comment: Can you show me how this is done? 
Suppose I have this as my .js file:

var searchRE = new RegExp("red","gi"); 
var replace = 'blue'; 
for (var i=0;i<textNodes.snapshotLength;i++) { 
 var node = textNodes.snapshotItem(i); 
 node.data = node.data(searchRE, replace);
}

Should I just put document.createElement... here?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need of `RegExp`, you don't really need more than this (if I understand you correctly):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Test
// @version    0.1
// @description  Some useful description
// @match      https://www.your.site/*
// @resource html file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/Test.html
// ==/UserScript==

var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
var myHTML = GM_getResourceText("html");
myDiv.innerHTML = myHTML;
document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
```

The file `@resource` refers to is your html file where you've made you toolbar. You can also `@require` your own CSS file so your html doesn't need to include style rules in every single tag.

What this does is reading your local file, and throwing that into a new div in the body.
You could also make the whole html in javascript, but that is a long and tiresome process with a higher risk of errors.

**NOTE**
Some sites (like [Google](https://www.google.com/)) does for some reason not like this method, and throws this into a hidden `iframe` instead, which makes it a bit harder to make it look good. I tested this on several sites, and on basic sites, this method should work!